# How to use jazzy with Objective C .m (implementation) files?

Tags: objective-c, documentation, jazzy

I love jazzy, but I struggle with the Objective C process. Many classes are documented well in the .m files but not the .h files.  If I put the .m file names in the umbrella header, jazzy blows up. Besides copying the comments to the .h files, is there a less manually intensive way of getting good results?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I haven't written much objective-c code, lately. I write everything in Swift now and put it into packages when possible.  jazzy works great for this., and I can help you with that if you get stuck. Otherwise, sorry I can't be of more help to you. 